# Salesforce: find how many records have duplicate values

Tags: reporting, salesforce, validation

I'm changing a field to be unique, but currently some accounts have the same value in that field.

How can I get a count of how many fields currently have non-unique values in that field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can run a SOQL aggregate query to find the values that aren't unique, e.g.

```
select name from account group by name having count(name) > 1
```

[Edit] You can also count each value, e.g. this will show you how many rows have each non unique value.

```
select name, count(id) num from account group by name having count(name) > 1
```